# How to reset settings in Visual Studio Code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, when I try to install something, I lose the "-" sign to collapse the JSX code, as shown below:

[image]

How to make it appear again? Or how to reset it to the default settings of VS Code?

Comment: This is an image about my problem.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKAUz.png